# remove a value and its corresponding value in a table

Tags: r, awk

In a file (1000 columns, 2000 rows), for each column there is another column next to it. something like:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
3      3    4    4     4     6
6      5    2    2     5     1
9      1    3    5     4     1
2      5    6    4     8     5
6      1    5    2     3     1
```

I want to remove those values which their corresponding value is 1
the result:

```
[,1] [,3] [,5] 
3    4     4
6    2     8
2    3
     6
     5
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include what have you tried. You paste in the code, and the use the format tool at the top of the input box that looks like '{}'. Good luck.

Comment: The relationship between your input and your output given your statement that you "want to remove those values which their corresponding value is 1" is obscure. Try again, clarifying WHY that's your expected output. Where did column 4 go, for example?

Comment: @EdMorton Apparently, the second block is the expected output. The odd columns are filtered by the even columns.

Comment: @mplourde basically, I need only values in odd columns but before that I want to filter them based on corresponding values in even columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To echo what @shellter said, it's both helpful and polite to include what you've tried in the question.

Here's a compact way to accomplish this using `split` and `mapply`.

```
d <- read.table(text='3      3    4    4     4     6
6      5    2    2     5     1
9      1    3    5     4     1
2      5    6    4     8     5
6      1    5    2     3     1', header=FALSE)

cols <- split(as.list(d), rep(1:2, length.out=length(d)))
mapply(function(col1, col2) col1[col2 != 1], 
       cols[[1]], cols[[2]], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

# $V1
# [1] 3 6 2
# 
# $V3
# [1] 4 2 3 6 5
# 
# $V5
# [1] 4 8
```

Comment: @Maryam hmm, works fine for me. I tried I few different things to reproduce the error you're having, but couldn't.